# Power App - response from Flow is not treated as json

Tags: json, powerapps, power-automate

I have a power app that wants to collect some data from a rest API, I am using Flow as this seems to be the recommended way.

I have a collection:

```
[
    {id: 1,name: "test",lines: [
            {id: 244,
                StrategyId: 1,
                TypeId: 0,
                Weight: 10,
                toWeight: 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {id: 3,name: "test2",lines: [
            {id: 262,
                StrategyId: 3,
                TypeId: 0,
                Weight: 0,
                toWeight: 200
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I enter this into a formula straight up, it works fine:

```
ClearCollect( CityPopulations, json...)
```

However, when I try to fetch the data from Flow it only returns a collection with one single entry that is the json data as string.

```
 Set('CityPopulations','PowerApp->Sendmeamobilenotification'.Run());ClearCollect(NewTable, CityPopulations.testoutput);
```

In Microsoft flow I use PowerApps trigger and Respond to PowerApps.

Also note that there are no " on the propertynames in json structure, but this was the only way I could get Power Apps to actually accept typing in json manually. I have tried having the respons propper, as well as this way. I had to adjust the flow to remove the " around propertynames. Still same result.

This is how the table looks in collections: 
[image]

This is how it looks when I am entering the data manually:

[image]

this is the direct output from :

```
{
  "testoutput": "[{id:1,name:\"test\",lines:[{id:244,StrategyId:1,TypeId:0,fromWeight:10,toWeight:200}]},{id:2,name:\"tester\",lines:[{id:154,StrategyId:2,TypeId:0,fromWeight:10,toWeight:200}]}]"
}
```

The biggest difference is the escape characters added from flow.

[image]

Comment: can you write/show how exactly json is retruned from Flow,
I mean paste it somewhere on Text field just to see if format is right?

Comment: I added some more informtion in the question, I can't copy the entire JSON since its massive and not all information is to be shared publically, at least not in text format, but I have added some images from flow and from power apps.

Answer (score 3):

This took me quite some time to solve so maybe will help others.

When you want to return an array (collection) form Flow to a Canvas App you need to use **Response (Request)**, not Respond to PowerApps.

All the problems go away with that

Tip: Remember to provide a SCHEMA and to remove and re-add the flow in the canvas app

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Collecting a single column of Text **from** the API Response rather than collecting the entire response.

**Try just using:**
`ClearCollect(colNewTable,'PowerApp->Sendmeamobilenotification'.Run())`

If you want to set `colNewTable` as a variable, wrap it like:

`Set(varNewTable,ClearCollect(colNewTable,'PowerApp->Sendmeamobilenotification'.Run())`

Hope this helps!

Comment: From what I can gather, powerapps doesn't really support fetching json data from Flow, only Text? The json that is sent back is an actually array, but is used as a text string in the powerapp. I changed to fetching data directly as a datasource and it works fine.