# In Powerapps; present folders and files in a gallery

Tags: json, power-automate, powerapps

I have tried following several online guides but the results are never quite what I need.

The closest I have come is to use **Power Automate** (Flow named: PAFolderRtn)
[image]

with **'Get files (properties only)'**
Then a **'Select'** to just get the columns I want

The (Text) output through **'Respond to a PowerApp or flow'** is;

```
{
  "rtntm": "2023-11-20T13:03:34.5025608Z",
  "rtnoutput": {
    "body": [
      {
        "FileNameExt": "Delivery Partner",
        "isFolder": "True",
        "Path": "CDS/3_Service Area/"
      },
      {
        "FileNameExt": "CDS_ElectricCar_BookingSheet.xlsx",
        "isFolder": "False",
        "Path": "CDS/3_Service Area/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Back in **PowerApps**,
A button runs;

```
OnSelect = Set(PAFR,PAFolderRtn.Run("/CDS/3_Service Area/"))
```

and in the Gallery

```
Items = Table(ParseJSON(PAFR.rtnoutput))
```

So far I get 'expected string but got object' Error

Thanks for anyone's help on this!

NB:
I tried referring the output to the Get Files body but have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted this question after several days trying different methods and found the answer in a vaguely related question;
[answer from 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935694/power-app-response-from-flow-is-not-treated-as-json?rq=2)

Their answer was brief so I found a walkthrough of Request vs Response here;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV9AkIQmemI

The issue was my final step, 'Respond to a PowerApp', is not passing complex data back to Apps, NB: I have a HTTP request that does work by returning a JSON so I don't know what's up there.
Instead I used the Premium feature of 'Request' which returns my data as a Table!